# Where do I update Google account details in iOS13?

Tags: email, password, login, ios

I always changed email account passwords in Settings > Passwords & Accounts > (choose an account).

Now I can't see any password field there.  Same on two iPhone 7.
How can I update the password for an email account such as google?

Has this changed in the latest iOS?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's still there, can you add a screenshot of the settings page in question?

Comment: You might need to delete account and add it back if it is IMAP. Accounts like your work or study which didn’t use “Safari” or the web interface allow such password management.  Talking from iOS 12. @nohill did you check google? Or work ?

Comment: @ankii I checked my email accounts, all settings look the same as before the upgrade. Which is why it might help if the OP comes back and adds a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mistaking work accounts with Google ones. This is my work mail setup and my Gmail and Outlook look the way yours do. They don't offer explicit password fields in settings AFAIK. They use web interfaces as overlays, at the time of login.

As in macOS Mojave's mail too, there is no password field, Google is now using Safari.

So if you have changed the password of your Google account, it should automatically notify you and ask for password. But if you want to trigger it manually, try toggling off and on the mail  switch from the list.

For a drastic approach(if it's a big mailbox), Deleting it and adding it back will allow you to change the password.

> [image]

Comment: weird, I managed to update the passwords in Settings > Passwords&Accounts > Websites and account passwords.  They're working fine now.  I never changed them there that I remember.

Comment: Wait, which one did you want to change ? Those in autofill ?

Comment: No.  I mean the only way I could change the passwords was in Settings > Passwords&Accounts > Websites and account passwords